# MongoDB copyDatabase runs index creation on foreground not background

Tags: mongodb

I have 700M rows / 1.3TB MongoDB instance, version 1.6.3. I tried to copy it to new 2.0 instance with `copyDatabase` command.

'Just copying' was done by 2 hours. But after that, new MongoDB collection locked and `db.currentOp()` returns below result.

```
{
    "opid" : 5,
    "active" : true,
    "lockType" : "write",
    "waitingForLock" : false,
    "secs_running" : 22138,
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "nerv",
    "query" : {
        "copydb" : 1,
        "fromhost" : "<some host>",
        "fromdb" : "<some db>",
        "todb" : "<some db>"
    },
    "client" : "127.0.0.1:50689",
    "desc" : "conn",
    "threadId" : "0x7f5094005700",
    "connectionId" : 1,
    "msg" : "index: (2/3) btree bottom up 214887968/715742197 30%",
    "progress" : {
        "done" : 214887968,
        "total" : 715742197
    },
    "numYields" : 5591738
},
```

I'm waiting about 5 hours and it looks this will not be ended within 24 hours. Do I have to wait this or is there any other options? ( like running index creation in background, as same as `ensureIndex` does )

---

Added) Thank you for answering, Adam C. Then I want to ask you more :)

1. What is `index: (2/3) btree bottom up` doing and why it is so slow?
2. I didn't meet `index: (3/3)` message, yet. Is `(3/3)` slow as same as `(2/3)`?

Comment: FYI : 'index: (3/3)' ends up very quickly. Don't worry, be happy. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring the issues with secondaries, index builds can be done in the background, but not as part of that copy I think:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+as+a+Background+Operation

You could just fsync and lock (or shut down temporarily) the 1.6.3 database and then copy the data files.  The file format has not changed between 1.6.3 and 2.0.6, so if you start up the 2.0.6 instance and point it at the appropriate path to the copied files you should be good to go.

In terms of the follow up pieces, that's a bit beyond my current knowledge, though I will try to find out.  I can say that the relevant code is here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/index_update.cpp#L219

It looks like you are in the btree building phase (after the read/insert) phase where the actual index data structure is being created, and the final piece is related to the commit.  Hard to gauge the exact timing here, but if you have been running for some time, in all likelihood it is worth letting it finish.

If it was my choice, I would have a plan B and be running the copy of the data files in parallel, assuming it is possible.  If the index build completes first, then kill the file transfer.

Update: I realized while researching another issue that there is a bug in versions up to 2.0.6 when the collection being indexed is substantially larger than RAM. It manifests as phase 2 of foreground indexing (what you are doing) taking a really long time, and a huge increase in the page fault rate.

The bug is fixed in 2.0.7 (as of writing this answer, available as a release candidate).  So, if anyone else runs into this, or the original question owner hits this problem, make sure you try with 2.0.7+

Comment: I added another questions. Thank you.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. ( Actually, I'm already doing Plan B before  asking here )

Comment: Sorry I didn't find this out sooner, but see my updated note in the answer if you are still having issues here.

Comment: I ran above command on the machine has 16GB RAM and the collection was 0.3TB with 1TB indexes - it did not fit absolutely.

Comment: However, I found a important note on the document page - 'Slaves and replica secondaries build indexes in the foreground even if background:true is specified.' Why mongo do like this?

Comment: That is actually a known bug, and has to do with how operations are replicated - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2771 - the workaround is to build the index on each replica set member separately (take them out of the set, build the index, re-add them to the set)